# Django | Filtro con formulario y managers devuelve todos los resultados sin filtrar

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Al hacer filtro mediante kword y managers con un formulario, devuelve todos los resultados en vez de lo que buscamos en el formulario.

**Archivo** views.py

```
class StationList(ListView):
    template_name = 'station/station_list.html'
    model = Station
    def station_list():
        palabra_clave = self.request.GET.get("kword",'')
        stations = Station.objects.buscar_estacion(palabra_clave)
        incidencias = Incidencia.objects.all()
        return render(request,'station/station_list.html', {'stations': stations, 'incidencias': incidencias})
```

**Archivo** managers.py

```
class StationManager(models.Manager):
    """Manager para el modelo Station"""
    def buscar_estacion(self, kword):
        resultado = self.filter(
            name__icontains=kword
        )
        return resultado
```

**Archivo** station_list.html

```
<form method="GET">{% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" id="kword" name="kword" placeholder="ingrese nombre">
  <button type="submit">Consultar</button>
</form>

{% for station in object_list %}
    {{ station.codigo }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Archivo** models.py

```
class Station(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Nombre',max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    objects = StationManager()

    def __str__(self):
        #return  [self.name]
        return str(self.id) + '-' + str(self.name)
```

**Archivo** urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',
        views.StationList.as_view(),
        name='station_list',
    ),
```

Comment: Dios mio, haces barbaridades xd, `station_list` es un metodo? Si es un metodo en que momento la ejecutas?... por otra parte **todo** funciona correctamente, lo que no entiendo es la funcion o metodo `station_list`...

Comment: xD Me encanta tu sinceridad Julio Cesar. Prometo procurar no hacer muchas barbaridades, claro que no me doy cuenta de ello por novato que soy jaja! En cuanto a la llama de ese método que comentas, debes tener razón de que no es llamado. ¿Lo debería llamar antes del "def"? Gracias una vez más por tu atención. (Conste que los proyecto que hago son por diversión, para aprender y sin ánimo de lucro).

Comment: No hay problema xd. Pues la vista es una `ListView`, lo que deberias hacer es sobrescribir los metodos `get_queryset` y `get_context_data`, pero no se muy bien que quieres hacer, ademas si seria mejor una vista basada en funcion o en clase...

Comment: Lo único que pretendo hacer es que filtre el name con lo que escribo en el form. Ejemplo si escribo "PU" me devuelva la estación PUERTO únicamente y no toda la lista de estaciones como lo hace actualmente. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza `stations` como fuente del resultado. `object_list` siempre contendrá todos los registros del modelo.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/

```
{% for station in stations %}
    {{ station.codigo }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Si utilizo stations como comentas, no me devuelve ningún resultado (haga búsqueda o no). Gracias de todos modos F.Igor